# How would you create a script to compare two systems users email addresses

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare a list of users in 1 system, to a group of Active Directory members.

I have it working in the reverse order, but that is wrong!

The CSV is a list of people's names and their email address (column : "Email")

```
#Script to compare Program Users to AD Group

$Date = Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy
$ProgramList = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\Program_users_list_$Date.csv" | select -ExpandProperty "Email"| Where-Object {$_}
$ADGroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Program Users" | select SamAccountName

$ADEmail = @()
$Found = 0
$NotFound = 0
$Missing = @()

ForEach ($member in $ADGroupMembers){

$ADEmail += Get-ADuser -Identity $($member.samaccountname) -Properties emailaddress | select emailaddress

}

ForEach ($i in $ProgramList){

If ($i -contains $ADEmail){
#Write-Host "I found " $i
$Found = $Found + 1
}
Else {
#Write-Host "I did not find " $i
$NotFound = $NotFound + 1
$Missing += $i
}

}
Write-Host "I found $found  Group Members, but I cannot find: $Notfound in the Program List"
$Missing

Write-Host "Program Count: "$ProgramList.count

Write-Host "Group Count: "$ADEmail.count
```

When I run the script, every member of the $ProgramList gets put into $NotFound.

My If statement must be wrong, but I'm not sure what I'm missing...

What I *THINK* the If statement says is:
If this 1 email address from the ProgramList CSV is found in the Active Directory group, put that into the $Found variable.
If it isn't, put it into the $NotFound variable.

When I look what is in $ADEmail variable, I see the column header 'emailaddress'.  I don't know if this matters, but besides that, I see the list of 70 email address.

Program CSV = 75 email address.

AD Group = 70 email addresses

I then want the script to tell me what wasn't found - $Missing.

Comment: Consider using [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine all your statements to get the found and notfound email addresses like this,

Assumption: $ProgramList contains a list of email Addresses.

```
$ADEmail = (Get-ADGroupMember 'Program Users' | Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress

# Check if $ProgramList contains and not contains the list you generated above.
$Found = $ADEmail | ? { $ProgramList -contains $_ } # Intersection of two lists.
$NotFound = $ADEmail | ? {$ProgramList -notcontains $_ }

# You can print the count or the entire lists of email addresses ($Found and $NotFound)
Write-Output "Found $($Found.Count) Email addresses"
Write-Output "Not Found $($NotFound.Count) Email Addresses"
```

**EDIT**

The other way around would be

```
$Found = $ProgramList | ? { $ADEmail -contains $_ } # Intersection of two lists.
$NotFound = $ProgramList | ? {$ADEmail -notcontains $_ }
```

Comment: When I do this, I get 4 people not found.  The 4 that are not found exist in the AD group, but not in the ProgramList.  I kind of need this reversed, which is where I was getting stuck.  I need to make the the people in the program list are also in the AD group.  The AD group is used for email journaling.

Comment: @cowboydude99 updated the post. See below the original under Edit

Comment: That is awesome!  I see my logic failure....  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Same thinking, but with Compare-Object:

```
$ProgramList = (Import-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\Program_users_list_$Date.csv").Email.Where( {$_} )

$ADEmail = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Program Users" | Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress

$Compare = Compare-Object $ProgramList $ADEmail -IncludeEqual

$Found    = ($Compare | Where{ $_.SideIndicator -eq "==" }).Count
$Missing  = ($Compare | Where{ $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" }).InputObject
$NotFound = $Missing.Count

Write-Host "I found $found  Group Members, but I cannot find: $Notfound in the Program List"
$Missing
Write-Host "Program Count: "$ProgramList.count
Write-Host "Group Count: "$ADEmail.count
```

I didn't test it... You'll have to polish up some of the output yourself.

Comment: I used Jawad's solution above.  Thanks for your help though!!  I appreciate it.